# grab volume name of volumes over 85%

Tags: bash, scripts

I want from the output below grab all the volume names that have a capacity over 85%. I know that there isn't one in ths example but lets pretend there is. :)

```
Filesystem               total       used      avail capacity  Mounted on
/vol/mc3240a/            190GB       18GB      171GB      10%  /vol/mc3240a/
/vol/mc3240a/.snapshot       10GB      355MB     9884MB       3%  /vol/mc3240a/.snapshot
/vol/mc3240b_root_backup/      210GB     9019MB      201GB       4%  /vol/mc3240b_root_backup/
/vol/mc3240b_root_backup/.snapshot        0MB     1691MB        0MB     ---%  /vol/mc3240b_root_backup/.snapshot
```

Comment: To clarify, I want to grab the name, mc3240a, not the entire row

Comment: errr... I would use `df -hx tmpfs -x devtmpfs ` or something as the input...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df -h | egrep "(8[5-9]|9[0-9]|100)%" | cut -f 1 -d " "
```

- This will catch 85% up to 100% (the 0, does the {1}00%)
- The cut will show the 1st column (anything after the 1st space in the output is deleted; a device can not have a space)

Examples:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             139G  132G  218M 100% /
varrun                2.0G  368K  2.0G   1% /var/run
varlock               2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /var/lock
udev                  2.0G   48K  2.0G   1% /dev
devshm                2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm

$ df -h | egrep "(8[5-9]|9[0-9]|100)%" | cut -f 1 -d " "
/dev/sda1

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             144G  130G  7.5G  95% /
varrun                506M  148K  506M   1% /var/run
varlock               506M  4.0K  506M   1% /var/lock
udev                  506M   72K  506M   1% /dev
devshm                506M     0  506M   0% /dev/shm
$ df -h | egrep "(8[5-9]|9[0-9]|100)%" | cut -f 1 -d " "
/dev/sda1
```

Comment: but it does not catch 90...?!

Comment: but it catchs 81%, too

Comment: now, after editing this will do the job :D

Comment: @WolfgangVogl we almost got 3x the same answer now :D funny

Comment: Thx, this helped alot @Rinzwind . made a little modification `ssh root@hostname 'df -h' | egrep "(8[5-9]|9[0-9]|100)%" | cut -f 3 -d "/"`

Comment: @Jocke - you can also add `| sed -e 's/\/vol\///g'` to remove the `/vol` - `sed` can be useful...

Answer (score 2):

Like the other ones, but in a script to make sure it is all grabbed:

```
#!/bin/bash
#For 85% to 89%, and 95& to 99%
df -hx tmpfs -x devtmpfs | egrep '[8-9][5-9]%'
#To find if anything is 90%-94%
df -hx tmpfs -x devtmpfs | egrep '9[0-4]%'
#To find if anything is 100%
df -hx tmpfs -x devtmpfs | egrep '100%'
```

Sample input (`tmpfs` etc filtered out):

```
wilf@comp:~$ df -hx tmpfs -x devtmpfs
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        96G   21G   71G  23% /
/dev/sda3        58G   43G   12G  79% /home
/dev/sda5       357G  335G  4.2G  99% /run/media/wilf/Storage
/dev/sda6        27G   19G  6.8G  74% /run/media/wilf/433b971a
```

Sample output - with drive name with other stuff as I have not filtered that out:

```
wilf@comp:~$ ./testScript
/dev/sda5       357G  335G  4.2G  99% /run/media/wilf/Storage
```

---

Based @wolfgang 's , this should should print out just the drive name without the `/vol`:

```
df -hx tmpfs -x devtmpfs | egrep '(8[5-9]|9[0-9]|100)%' | cut -f 1 -d " " | sed -e 's/\/vol\///g'
```

Comment: yep, simplest (and i think best) is yours @Wilf - just use the alternative selection and all's done!

Comment: @WolfgangVogl - Your one-liner is better :D

Comment: @wilf in the end we all end up with the same line. Now what :D :D

Comment: @Rinzwind - Dunno :)

Comment: @wilf you are forgetting to cut the result.OP wants device only ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind - the OP does not want `/vol` either - see the comment beloe [NullPointer's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/422591/178596)

Answer (score 2):

Try this (put it into a script, make it executable):

```
#!/bin/bash

DF_BIN='/bin/df'

DF_OUT=`${DF_BIN}`

tring='first line
second line
third line'

oldIFS="$IFS"   # store old IFS value
IFS='
'
IFS=${IFS:0:1} # tab formatting
lines=( $DF_OUT )

IFS=', '

COUNTER=0
for line in "${lines[@]}"
    do
        if [  $COUNTER -gt 0 ]; then    # strip first line
            fields=( $line )
            if [[ ${fields[4]} =~ (8[5-9]|[9][0-9]|100)%$ ]]; then
                echo "==> $line"
            fi
        fi
        let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
done

IFS="$oldIFS"

exit 0
```

Not as short as the answers above but it catches 85% to 100% in the right row...

or: SHORT one-line:

`df -hx tmpfs -x devtmpfs | egrep '(8[5-9]|9[0-9]|100)%'`

(edited Wilfs version) just like the other's solution but using egrep with alternatives)

Comment: Damn - I thought I could of done it as one-liner... Brilliant +1.

Comment: I like the one liner but I expect you need to cut the output to only show the device  ;)

Comment: What about `df -hx tmpfs -x devtmpfs | egrep '(8[5-9]|9[0-9]|100)%' | cut -f 1 -d " " | sed -e 's/\/vol\///g'`?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you are using commnad say `xyz` to get this output then

`xyz | grep "[8-9][5-9]%"`

should give you proper output

Comment: To clarify, I want to grab the name, mc3240a, not the entire row

Comment: That will be little tricky, I think...

Comment: I may be wrong, but wouldn't those not list numbers like 92%, as the second number is below 5? Same for @Rinzwind

Comment: think we got enough correct answers - but this one gives not 90 to 94 and 100 as you already told Wilf...